# Removing sensitive information from comment notifications - notify_post_author

Tags: notifications, pluggable

Basically I need to remove or comment our lines 1114 - 1116 in pluggable.php, and edit line 1113

These are the lines

```
$notify_message .= sprintf( __('Author : %1$s (IP: %2$s , %3$s)'), $comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_IP, $comment_author_domain ) . "\r\n";
$notify_message .= sprintf( __('E-mail : %s'), $comment->comment_author_email ) . "\r\n";
$notify_message .= sprintf( __('URL    : %s'), $comment->comment_author_url ) . "\r\n";
$notify_message .= sprintf( __('URL    : %s'), $comment->comment_author_url ) . "\r\n";
```

They are all part of function - wp_notify_postauthor

I can replace the whole thing by creating a plugin (which is what I've done)  - but is there a way to just change those affected lines - without replacing the whole function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[There is a hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1152) that should let you alter that data-- `comment_notification_text`.

```
add_action(
  'comment_notification_text',
  function($notify_message,$comment_id) {
    var_dump($notify_message,$comment_id);
    die;
  },
  10,2
);
```

You could parse that `$notify_message` string and remove the parts you don't want.

```
add_filter(
  'comment_notification_text',
  function($notify_message) {
    $notify_message = explode("\n",$notify_message);
    foreach ($notify_message as $k => $line) {
      $header = trim(substr($line,0,strpos($line,':')));
      switch ($header) {
        case 'E-mail':
        case 'URL' :
        case 'Whois':
          unset($notify_message[$k]);
        break;
        case 'Author' :
          $pat = '([^(]+)\(.*$';
          $notify_message[$k] = trim(preg_replace('|'.$pat.'|','$1',$line));
        break;
      }
    }
    $notify_message = implode("\n",$notify_message);
    return $notify_message;
  }
);
```

I think that accomplishes what you were going for.

Comment: Wow - this looks good... I guess I'd dump this in my functions php?

Comment: I should also clarify that I'm trying to remove any reference to the comment authors email or ip address - so for the author line its just the second two values I'm trying to drop (ip address and domain)

Comment: That should work from `functions.php`, a plugin, or a mu-plugin file.

Comment: It won't work with translation though. You will need to work that out yourself.

Comment: If you still see email address, change 'E-mail' to 'Email' - seems like the notification string has changed. (I'm on WP 4.7.)